# How to get git command on Cygwin 1.7

Tags: git, cygwin

I have already installed cygwin on my system, its version is 1.7.24. But however when I try to clone any repo it says "bash: git: command not found". What needs to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must explicitly install git, it is not included in the base install selection. From memory (I am not sitting on a windows computer right now), you run the setup program and when you come to the install various packages git should be available in the Development group. Git will be listed as "not installed", click on the line to mark it for installation and continue.